# Use *args without putting the arguments into a tuple?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, arguments, tuples

Here is my code:

```
def main(*args):
    # The following code will look for arguments and record their start and
    # end positions.
    arg = False
    arg_invalid = False
    arg_start = -1
    arg_end = -1
    i = 1

    print("main args = " + str(args))
```

... stripped irrelevant code ...

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("sys args = " + str(sys.argv))
    print("tuple'd args = " + str(tuple(sys.argv)))
    main(sys.argv)
```

And the output:

```
$ ./gmanager.py foo bar 128
sys args = ['./gmanager.py', 'foo', 'bar', '128']
tuple'd args = ('./gmanager.py', 'foo', 'bar', '128')
main args = (['./gmanager.py', 'foo', 'bar', '128'],)
```

As you can see, after `main()` is called, `main()` places its arguments into a tuple. I do not want this as it makes for complicated argument / string referencing (`arg[x][y][z]`).

Is there a way to accept arguments as their prior state in my `main()` function, or can I strip the tuple from outside my arguments?

Comment: The `*` prefix works both ways: `if __name__ == '__main__': main(*sys.argv)`

Comment: If that doesn't answer your question, you'll have to be more clear about what you're trying to accomplish. What variables in `main()` do you need bound to what parts of `sys.argv`?

Comment: My arguments are whatever are in `sys.argv`. Before they were called in `main()` they were a list (`[]`). After they were called in `main()` they are a list inside a tuple (`([])`). I just want the list.

Comment: That's a confusing description. Don't use prose. Create a code sample showing what *should* be the value of what in the end, even if you don't know how to get to that point.

Comment: Oh, I just understood the meaning of your first comment. I didn't realise that `*` expanded a list - I thought it just made room for it. If you'd like to put that in an answer then I can upvote it.

Comment: In a function *signature*, it gathers all extra positional arguments into a tuple/list. In a function *call*, it expands a list into positional arguments (whether required or optional). (This is [tutorial-level material](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#more-on-defining-functions), maybe you should brush up on it.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either pass the list in directly:

```
def main(args):
    ...

main(sys.argv)
```

or use `*` to perform argument unpacking:

```
def main(*args):
    ...

main(*sys.argv)
```

The latter is useful for testing, as you can write e.g.

```
main('foo', 'arg1', 'arg2')
```

to simulate command-line arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want exactly one  parameter to `main()`, and you want it to be a `list`, just get rid of the `*` in `def main`, like so:

```
def main(args):
  print str(args)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  import sys
  main(sys.argv)
```